# Select named index level from pandas DataFrame MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I created a dataframe as :

```
df1 = pandas.read_csv(ifile_name,  header=None,  sep=r"\s+",  usecols=[0,1,2,3,4],
                              index_col=[0,1,2], names=["year", "month", "day", "something1", "something2"])
```

now I would like to create another dataframe where year>2008. Hence I tried :

```
df2 = df1[df1.year>2008]
```

But getting error :

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'year'
```

I guess, it is not seeing the "year" among the columns because I defined it within index. But how can I get data based on year>2008 in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that `year` is an index rather than a column. One solution is to use [`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), which lets you use index names directly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2005, 2010, 2015], 'value': [1, 2, 3]})
df = df.set_index('year')

res = df.query('year > 2008')

print(res)

      value
year       
2010      2
2015      3
```

Answer (score 7):

Get the level by name using `MultiIndex.get_level_values` and create a boolean mask for row selection:

```
df2 = df1[df1.index.get_level_values('year') > 2008]
```

If you plan to make modifications, create a copy of `df1` so as to not operate on the view.

```
df2 = df1[df1.index.get_level_values('year') > 2008].copy()
```

Comment: Will making modification to a view `df2` affect the original `df1` in any way?  If not, why make a copy? Thank  you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your index is sorted

```
df.loc[2008:]
Out[259]: 
      value
year       
2010      2
2015      3
```